# How to insert infinite audio into the live streaming by using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I use the following command to insert infinite audio into `rtsp` stream, but `-stream_loop -1` didn't work. How to fix it?

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.31.104/h264/ch1/main/av_stream  -stream_loop -1 -i blank.aac  -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/test
```

This is the full console when I executed the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.31.140:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0" -f lavfi -i anullsrc -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -f flv rtmp://live.lamp.mowainfo.com:11935/live/test

mowa@OpenWRT-Dev:~$ ffmpeg -i "rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.31.140:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0" -f lavfi -i anullsrc -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -f flv rtmp://live.lamp.mowainfo.com:11935/live/test
ffmpeg version N-86764-ga824685 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 67.100 / 55. 67.100
  libavcodec     57.100.104 / 57.100.104
  libavformat    57. 75.100 / 57. 75.100
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 95.100 /  6. 95.100
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.31.140:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0':
  Metadata:
    title           : RTSP Session/2.0
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 25.08 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Input #1, lavfi, from 'anullsrc':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 44100 Hz, stereo, u8, 705 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_u8 (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[rtsp @ 0x23d0520] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[libx264 @ 0x244d200] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x244d200] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x244d200] 264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://live.lamp.mowainfo.com:11935/live/test':
  Metadata:
    title           : RTSP Session/2.0
    encoder         : Lavf57.75.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 25.08 fps, 1k tbn, 25.08 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.100.104 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.100.104 aac
Past duration 0.642738 too large   13286kB time=00:03:50.22 bitrate= 472.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=4 speed=0.985x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a blank audio, then you can use a source filter:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.31.104/h264/ch1/main/av_stream -f lavfi -i anullsrc=cl=mono -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/test
```

This will produce a mono 44100 Hz stream. Add `-ac 2` for stereo. Add `-ar N` for a different sampling rate e.g. `-ar 48000` for a 48 kHz stream.

Comment: I want to do this now: for `rtsp` with audio, don't insert blank audio; for `rtsp` without audio, insert blank audio. What should I do?

Comment: Nothing. Since there's no `-map` assignments present, ffmpeg will choose one audio stream from among the inputs. If the rtsp has audio, it should choose that.

Comment: I tried it with a stream containing audio, but when I pulled the live streaming from server, it didn't have audio.

Comment: Show the full console output.